# How to use computer vision to find corners of a soccer field based on location coordinates?

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, corner-detection, robocup

I want to use computer vision to allow my robot to detect the corners of a soccer field based on its current position. 
Matlab has a detectHarrisFeatures feature, but I believe it is only for 2D mapping.

The approach that I want to try is to collect the information of the lines (using line detection), store them in a histogram, and then see where the lines intersect based on their angles.

My questions are:

- How do I know where the lines intersect?
- How do I find the angles of the lines using computer vision?
- How do I update this information based on my coordinates?

I am in the beginning stages of this task, so any guidance is much appreciated!

Comment: also how would I deal with partial occlusion of the lines?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Hough Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform) to find the lines and their equations in an image. once you have that, finding an intersection between the 2 lines comes down to solving a linear equation with 1 variable.

Comment: would this work if the robot is receiving input as it moves (through its central vision) as opposed to us having a bird's eye view? also, is there then no need to find the angles?

Comment: what my thoughts were, were that once we find the lines of different angles, we can remove duplicates by clustering them into bins in the histogram

Comment: To your first question: can you clarify what it means "receiving input as it moves"? are you receiving input as RGB images?

For your second questions: with the hough transform you are computing the angles and distance (to some reference point in the image) anyway, so it does solve your problems :)